# Google Sheets, Moving from one Tab to another via input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get this script working where it will work when I put a "yes" or "no" for a choice it will move based on the "yes" to the targeted sheet "Completed Dispatch"

The original sheet is called "Tracker" and the column that I need it to check the "Yes or No" is called "Dispatched"

It doesn't work and I am not that great in GAS

The actual problem I am having is when I make the decision from no to Yes it does not move the row and does not do anything at all.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var ss = e.source,
        sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
        range = e.range,
        targetSheet,
        columnNumberToWatch = 9; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc
    if (sheet.getName() === "Tracker" && e.value === "Dispatched" && e.range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {
        targetSheet = "Completed Dispatch"
    } else if (sheet.getName() === "Completed Dispatch" && e.value === "Incomplete" && e.range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {
        targetSheet = "Tracker"
    }
    ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)
        .appendRow(sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
            .getValues()[0])
    sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: Quote the error. Or Explain what doesn't work? Describe your problem.

Comment: I edited it. but basically It just does not move the row when I have the input value go from yes to no.

Comment: Is there other code that this is a part of? I wondering about "`source`", "`targetSheet`", "`.columnStart`", "`.rowStart`", "`.getValues()[0]`". In any event, I strong suggest that you write the code as a "simple" function (get rid of the OnEdit aspect). Then run Debug to see the values of the various parameters. Once you iron that code, you can convert to OnEdit(e).